# Chevron part of back bar button item missing

Tags: ios, ios8, uibarbuttonitem, back-button

The Chevron of the Back button of the navigation controller, when there is segue between 2 screens, suddenly disappears as seen here.

[image: To the left of "Screen 1", there is no chevron/back arrow]

Wonder why that is happening?

Comment: Are you using push Segue?

Comment: Yes I am using Push Segue.

Comment: self.navigationController.interactivePopGestureRecognizer.enabled = NO;
Try this one, because stack of views are overlapping..Hope it will work.. use this in viewWIllAppear